# Как одновременно перейти на новую страницу и скачать файл yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Мой фрагмент кода, но в случае если первый if не выполняется, перехода на нужную страницу не происходит, а лишь только скачивание файла. Как обойти это?

```
if($this->flag == 1){               
                Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setTo($this->email)
                    ->setFrom(['@gmail.com' => Yii::$app->params['senderName']])
                    ->setReplyTo([$this->email => $this->fromPerson])
                    ->setSubject("Ваш конверт")                                  
                    ->attachContent($pdf->Output('', 'S'), ['fileName' => 'pdfName.pdf',   'contentType' => 'application/pdf'])
                    ->send();                                
            }            
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . 'enelope.pdf');
            exit($pdf->Output('', 'S'));  // работает не коорректно, не переводит на нужную страницу
```

Comment: никак. или одно или другое

Comment: @Ипатьев я понимаю, что либо одно, либо другое, обходное решение должно же быть

Comment: ну если должно быть, то ты легко найдешь его в интернете и сможешь дать нам ссылку на него

Answer (score 0):

Одновременно отдать пользователю файл и перейти на другой `URL` нельзя. По крайней мере в рамках одного окна браузера или одной вкладки. Если Вам все же это нужно у Вас только один выход - Вы переходите на новую страницу и у нее в заголовках выставляете мета-тег `refresh` с линком на скачиваемый файл и временем через которое нужно запустить скачку файла.

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=https://example.com/download/myfile.pdf">
```

В данном примере, после загрузки страницы, через 5 секунд запустится скачивание файла `myfile.pdf`

Данное решение может не подойти, если Вы по каким-то причинам не желаете, чтобы файлы лежали в публичном доступе и их мог кто угодно скачать и поэтому файл находится за пределами корня сайта и отдается только через `php`-файл у которого есть доступ к этому файлу локально.

Хотя и это в принципе можно обойти. Вы для каждого такого файла формируете уникальную ссылку которая помимо всего имеет еще и `время жизни`, по истечению которого она удаляется. Например, все ссылки будут вида `https://example.com/download/<md5(от текущего времени + id пользователя)/<имя файла>` Вы отдаете все обращения вида `https://example.com/download/</S+{32}>/(\S+)` отдельному `php`-файлу. Он получает уникальную ссылку из этого `URL` проверяет что она существует в `БД`, понимает какому пользователю эта ссылка принадлежит, получает из `URL` имя файла, проверяет что именно эта ссылка связана с этим именем и этим пользователем, проверяет что не истекло `время жизни` - отдает файл пользователю на скачку. Ну и можно еще как только кто-то лезет в `БД` за этой информацией автоматически удалять ссылки с истекшим временем жизни из БД,либо помечать их как удаленные.